# W3c Validator complains about multiple ID DIV?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have this annoying problem I came through by validating my HTML.

First of all, I have this two WHILE LOOPS in PHP that output DIVs with different CLASS name and ID name.

However, I am also using JQuery for to toggle my DIV. Whenever I get rid of my ID DIV "station_info" it will show all the content inside that DIV on screen and the toggle wont work BUT if I leave it as it is, it will complain about the duplicate ID "station_info_#number".

Can anyone help me please.

here is my [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4xu0rwgu/)

thanks in advance.

[image: Duplicate ID DIV.. you can see the content inside of it is different]

**CSS:**

```
/* desk boxes*/
.desk_box_ver{ 
width: 18px;
height: 33px;
}   

.desk_box_ver:hover{
cursor: pointer;
}


.desk_box_hor{ 
width: 23px;
height: 10px;
}   
.desk_box_hor:hover{
cursor: pointer;
}

.desk_box_hor, .desk_box_ver { 
position: absolute; 
border: 4px solid black; 
padding:10px;
}

/*station info*/
.station_info_ {
display: none;
z-index: 100;
position: absolute;
background-color: #F2F2F2;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #B2B2B2;
height: 200px;
margin-left: 50px;
width:  275px;
border:4px solid black;
}
```

**JS/Jquery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    //Display station information in a hidden DIV (station_info_) that is toggled with a closing (X) button
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                    $(".desk_box_hor").add(".desk_box_ver").click(function() {
                        var id = $(this).attr("data-rel")
                    var st = $("#station_info_"+id).toggle();
                    if (!st.has(".close").length) {
                    st.prepend('<button class="close">X</button>');
                    }//end if
                    });//end click
                    });//end ready

                    //Make the (x) button toggle
                    $(document).on("click",".close", function () {
                    $(this).parent().toggle(); 
                    });//end click close
      </script>
```

**HTML/PHP:**

```
//this is in a while loop and works
echo '<div class="' . $class . '" data-rel="' . $id . '" style="left:' . $x_pos . 'px;top:' . $y_pos.'px;">' . $sta_num . '</div>' . "\n";


//this is in another  while loop and the TOGGLE does work fine
echo '<div class="station_info_" id="station_info_' . $id . '" style="left:' . $x_pos . 'px;top:' . $y_pos . 'px;"><p class="numb">User:' . $user .'<br>Station:' . $hostname . '<br>Pod:' . $sta_num . '<br>Section:' . $sec_name . '<br>State:' . $state . '<br></p>' . $circle . '</div>' . "\n";
```

**the error messages on W3C Validator:**

Error Line 494, Column 79: Duplicate ID station_info_253.
…nfo_253" style="left:524px;top:353px;">User:CHREI8
Station:…
✉
Warning Line 354, Column 79: The first occurrence of ID station_info_253 was here.

So as you can see, it is being duplicated, I know because the ID has to be unique but if I change it to class all of my content inside the DIV "station_info_#" will corrupt and show everywhere on screen.

Comment: im not clear on why you cant use a calss

Comment: your approaches to the question is not helpfull, *how do i use  a clsss instead of an id* in the js, is what you really want to know

Comment: In my Jquery function where I do **var st = $("#station_info_"+id).toggle();** if I put a  dot "." instead of "#" the toggle wont work. Still the W3C will complain about duplicate ID from the station_info DIV

Comment: in the fiddle the ids are unique

Comment: For a W3C validation, we need the real URL to try to validate your page, maybe some others DIVs use these IDs...